# How to map a function using multiple boolen columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database of New York apartments which has thousands of rented apartments. What I'm trying to do is create another column based on "pet_level". Their are two other columns 'dog_allowed' and 'cat_allowed' that have a 0 or 1 if the pet is allowed

I'm looking to create the 'pet_level' column on this:
0 if no pets are allowed
1 if cats_allowed
2 if dogs_allowed
3 if both are allowed

my initial approach at solving this was as follows:

```
df['pet_level'] = df.apply(lambda x: plev(0 = x[x['dog_allowed'] == 0 & x['cat_allowed'] == 0] ,1 = x[x['cat_allowed'] == 1], 2 = x[x['dog_allowed'] == 1], 3 = x[x['dog_allowed'] == 1 & x['cat_allowed'] == 1]))
```

Just because I've done smaller test datasets in a similar manner

I tried out a lambda function using the apply method but that doesn't seem to allow for that.

Comment: Please provide you attempt at solving this

Comment: check out : [pandas series map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: This is what I thought would be a initial good way of solving which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that is currently working, define a function with the conditional statements needed.

```
def plvl(db):
    if db['cats_allowed'] == 0 and db['dogs_allowed'] == 0:
        val = 0
    elif db['cats_allowed'] == 1 and db['dogs_allowed'] == 0:
        val = 1
    elif db['cats_allowed'] == 0 and db['dogs_allowed'] == 1:
        val = 2
    elif db['cats_allowed'] == 1 and db['dogs_allowed'] == 1:
        val = 3
    return val
```

Then pass in that function by applying the function along the columns(`axis=1`) to create the desired column.

```
df['pet_level'] = df.apply(plvl, axis=1)
```

I'm not sure if this is the most performance efficient but for testing purposes it currently works. I'm sure there's are more pythonic approaches that would be less demanding and equally helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping, you can vectorize the operation like this:

```
df['pet_level'] = df['dog_allowed'] * 1 + df['cat_allowed'] * 2
```